# How do I workout the correct cordinates with resolution from a screenshot in cv2?

Tags: python, opencv

Im learning to use Open CV and Im doing a basic example of template matching of locating and image within an image, but im having an issue with resolution.

It takes a screengrab finds the targetimage, marks it with a dot, but when I ask pyautogui to click that position it ends up clicking near but off

```
Max Loc: (623, 717)
```

When the actual cordinates are

```
339,550
```

I think it has something to do with the resolution of the screen as im 1920x1200 but the screenshot is 2880x1800 so its getting the cordinates from that I would think its just half but tried that and thats why Im here.

see code below:

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    import keyboard
import mss
import cv2
import numpy
from time import time, sleep
import pyautogui

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0

sct = mss.mss()
screen_grab_dimensions = {
    'left': 70,
    'top': 185,
    'width': 750,
    'height': 500
}

coin = cv2.imread('coin2.png')

w = coin.shape[1]
h = coin.shape[0]

while True:
    
    #GET SCREENGRAB WITH CORDINATES
    scr = numpy.array(sct.grab(screen_grab_dimensions))
    scr_remove = scr[:,:,:3]

    #MATCH IMAGE WITHIN IMAGE
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(scr_remove, coin, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    
    #GET AND PRINT ACCURACY AND LOCATION
    _, max_val, _, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    print(f"Max Val: {max_val} Max Loc: {max_loc}")
    
    #???
    src = scr.copy()
    
    #IF ACCURACY IF ABOVE .90 MARK IT WITH A DOT
    if max_val > .90:
    
        mx =  max_loc
        my = (max_loc[0] + w, max_loc[1] + h)
        
        #WORKOUT CENTER OF COIN
        centerpoint = ( int((max_loc[0] + (w/2))), int((max_loc[1] + (h/2))))
        
        #MARK WITH A DOT
        cv2.circle(scr,centerpoint,10,(255,0,0),-1)
        
        #CLICK AREA
        pyautogui.click(x=centerpoint)

    
    #RESIZE FOR ME
    scr = cv2.resize(scr, (0,0), fx=.5, fy=.5)
    
    #SHOW ME SCREENSHOT
    cv2.imshow('Screen Shot', scr)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    sleep(.1)
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        break
```

[image: screengrab]

Comment: You would normally take the ratio of screen vs image and multiply that  by the coordinate. But that does not work out. So there must be some offset or further reduction of the image area on the screen.

Comment: "half" makes no sense. 2880/1920 = 1.5, 1800 / 1200 = 1.5

Comment: I tried 1.5x, but that does not work with the values he gave. So there is likely some offset or the screen area is limited for the image part and/or offset

Comment: BTW, the line immediately after the `#???` comment , which is `src = scr.copy()`, is creating a deep copy (all values of the `src` object are copied exactly in a new variable) of `src`... but it then assigns the newly-created deep copy to its original variable, `src`, putting in question the relevance of that operation. You typically create a deep copy of an object because you will modify the original object in your program and you want to have a "backup" of the original data for a future relevant operation.

Comment: Thanks @stateMachine :) had no clue.